# Replace several strings in text with javascript- how to add more varables

Tags: javascript

I'm using a Javascript to to replace/remove two words in a string of text. However, I need to add a few more words, and instead of duplicate the script like i have done in the example, how do I add more words to the first query?

Im also wondering if its possible to remove a certain string with spaces between? Say i want to remove if it´s exactly this words"- French keyboard" but keep them if it´s "Microsoft French keyboard" for an example. Can I target an array of exact words?

I'm aware of the amount of topics on this, but I couldn't find any that I could figure out.

The script:

```
$('document').ready(
function() {
$("#centerplist .products .datainfo a:contains('keyboard')").text(
  function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/keyboard/g, "");
  }
  ).addClass("eu");
 }

 );
 $('document').ready(
 function() {
 $("#centerplist .products .datainfo a:contains('French')").text(
  function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/French/g, "");
  }
  ).addClass("eu");
  }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the regexp (you actually already using it):

```
$(this).text().replace(/(French|keyboard)/g, "");
```

And, of course in such case do not use selector `:contains('French')` or use both of them (I suggest to use just `$("#centerplist .products .datainfo a')`

Comment: Thanks, will gives this a try. also updated the question in regards to removal of certain sentences-

Comment: Hmm. Couldnt get it to work when removing the contain selector. How do I properly use both selectors?

Comment: The reason is not the selector. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4btg2oj/

Comment: Thanks @Roland Bertolom, that helped! I saw I could fill in sentences regexp too, which is perfect!